# What is the difference between a cache, a primed cache and an empty cache?

Tags: web-server, web-hosting, website, cache

Can someone explain the following concepts to me as the relate to measuring the data transfer of data from my web site.

Whats the difference between a cache, a primed cache and an empty cache?

Can you give a a definition for each?

Answer (score 13):

**Cache:** Some sort of memory-space for data to be stored, from here it is possible to retrieve data faster than the source location, in order to improve performance. For example, RAM on a computer can be used as cache for data on hard disk to improve performance. Another example is a web browser that has a local copy of something because it is faster than grabbing it over the net.

**Primed Cache**: A Cache that contains some of the data from the source location. So with the browser example, you may have a copy of an image saved on disk or in memory so you don't have to grab it over the net.

**Empty Cache:** Cache space that is available but has yet to have anything loaded into it. You have space to store some image from a web page, but never retrieved it so you don't have a cached copy yet.